# Cakephp 3 - var not transmitted to view when exception thrown

Tags: error-handling, cakephp-3.0

In my AppController, I define a variable that must be used in every views (including error400.ctp, error500.ctp) of my app:

```
// /src/Controller/AppController.php
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $foo = 'bar';
    $this->set(compact('foo'));
}
```

It works well, except when an exception is thrown (like NotFoundException): I get the following error:

`Undefined variable: foo in /src/Template/Error/error400.ctp`

Is this a normal behavior of cakephp? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behaviour, what is basically happening:

1. Exception is thrown (`beforeFilter` was called depending on where was it thrown, e.g. it is called for MissingAction or MissingTemplate, but not for MissingController).
2. Request handling is aborted and `ErrorHandler` steps in to catch and handle that Exception.
3. To render the Exception, `ErroHandler` uses `ExceptionRenderer`, which in turn creates special `ErrorController`, that kind of replaces original controller. This also means, that now you have completely different controller handling the request (new instance of Controller class), so even if `beforeFilter` was called and `$foo` was set, it is not longer valid.
4. `ExceptionRenderer` will use its own `render()` method to create output for error page.

To customize this, you can extend that default `ExceptionRenderer`, so you will be able to set variables to `ErrorController`

```php
<?php
// goes in src/Error/AppExceptionRenderer
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer
{
    public function render()
    {
        $this->controller->set('foo', 'bar');
        return parent::render();
    }
}
```

Set this class as default ExceptionRenderer in `app.php`

```php
//...
'Error' => [
    // ...
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'App\Error\AppExceptionRenderer',
    // ...
],
```

So you need to set that global view variable in two places. Use some common method from models, `Configure` class to read global variables or whatever is suitable for your requirements.

More on custom error handling: **[Extending and Implementing your own Exception Handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#extending-and-implementing-your-own-exception-handlers)**