# Is it possible to use AppController on error pages? (Cakephp 3.1)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I am trying to render error templates (eg error400.ctp) but with the default layout (site header and footer) which relies on components and variables set in AppController. How do I tell Cake to use AppController when rendering error pages?

I have already tried making an ErrorController which extends AppController, but it breaks for missing actions.

Comment: I know, and that's not my question. Even with debug turned off the error views don't make use of AppController.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315153/cakephp-3-var-not-transmitted-to-view-when-exception-thrown) then.

Comment: `it breaks for missing actions.` -  That probably means an exception is thrown _whilst_ attempting to render the error page. The exception renderer [Simply uses your Error controller](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php#L111-L114) - if it exists, [falling back to use a controller object](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php#L129-L131) if that fails. Some debugging will probably help you solve your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my working ErrorController in case anyone comes looking for it:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class ErrorController extends AppController
{

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeRender($event);
        $this->viewBuilder()->templatePath('Error');
    }

}
```

There was a bug in one of my Components being loaded in AppController. When ErrorController extends AppController and one tries to access an invalid action in a controller it creates two instances of AppController and in my case a duplicate declaration of class error was thrown because of a bug in my component. This error caused some kind of loop causing the error page not to render.